# Container class and calling virtual methods with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I really can't find anything on the internet why my code not working as I expecting it:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "string.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;

class Animal {
private:
    char *name;
protected:
    enum { tele, empty } bendo;
public:
    Animal() {};
    Animal(const char *kname) : bendo(empty) {
        name = new char[strlen(kname) + 1];
        strcpy(name, kname);

    }
    const char *getname() { return name; }

    virtual ~Animal() {
        cout << "~" << name << endl;
        delete[] name;

    }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "Animal.print" << std::endl;
    }

};

class Monkey : public Animal {
protected:
    static const char* SOUND;
public:
    Monkey(const char *kname) : Animal(kname) { }

    ~Monkey() { cout << SOUND << SOUND << " "; }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "Monkey.print" << std::endl;
    }
};

const char* Monkey::SOUND = "Mak";

class Tiger : public Animal {
public:
    Tiger(const char *kname) : Animal(kname) { }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "Tiger.print" << std::endl;
    }

};

class Cage{
    Animal* animals;
    unsigned int num;
public:
    Cage(){};
    ~Cage();
    void add(const Animal* a) {
        Animal* tmp = new Animal[num + 1];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            tmp[i] = animals[i];
        tmp[num++] = *a;
        cout << "param: ";
        a->print(std::cout);
        cout << "in cage: ";
        tmp[num - 1].print(std::cout);
        animals = tmp;
    }
    void print(std::ostream& os) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            animals[i].print(os);
        }
    }

};


int main() {
    Animal *animal = new Animal("Animal");
    Animal *cicus = new Tiger("Cicus");
    Animal *csita = new Monkey("Csita");
    Animal *tarzan = new Monkey("AIAIAIAI");

    Cage* cage = new Cage;
    cout << "add animal" << endl;
    cage->add(animal);
    cout << endl << "add cicus" << endl;
    cage->add(cicus);
    cout << endl << "add csita" << endl;
    cage->add(csita);
    cout << endl << "add tarzan" << endl;
    cage->add(tarzan);

    cout << endl << "cage->print(cout);" << endl;
    cage->print(cout);
    cin.get();

}
```

So basically, what I would like to do here:

1. I have a class (Cage) which stores Animals.
2. Each animal has a print(...) method.
3. If I call cage.print(...), I would expect it to call all animals' print(...) method (Monkey.print(...), Tiger.print(...), etc), but it always calls the Animal.print(...) method. For this code, this is the output:

   ```
   add animal
   param: Animal.print
   in cage: Animal.print

   add cicus
   param: Tiger.print
   in cage: Animal.print

   add csita
   param: Monkey.print
   in cage: Animal.print

   add tarzan
   param: Monkey.print
   in cage: Animal.print

   cage->print(cout);
   Animal.print
   Animal.print
   Animal.print
   Animal.print
   ```

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

---

**SOLUTION**
Well, as @rodrigo said, I run into the so called 'object slicing' error, and to avoid this, I had to replace `Animal* animals` to `Animal** animals`, so I store not Animal objects but Animal **POINTERS**. I'm just copying here the important part of the code, so it's only shows the solution for this particular problem, so be careful, it misses other things (like memory handling!).

```
class Cage{
    Animal** animals; // We need to store pointers!
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned int max;
public:
    Cage(){
        num = 0;
        max = 10;
        animals = new Animal*[max];
    };

    void add(Animal* a) {
        /* Here I just 'optimized' a bit, 
but of course the best would be to use linked list. */
        if (num == max) {
            max*=2;
            Animal** tmp = new Animal*[max];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                tmp[i] = animals[i];
            }
            animals = tmp;
        }
        animals[num++] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not missing anything. Your code compiled cleanly, without errors, with gcc 5.3.1 (after removing the pragma).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I forgot to take that out of the code, but it isnt really that important :). (I had to place it in the code, because where I run it first, the compiler had problems with the strcpy method, and this was the fastest way to make the code runnable.)

Comment: You didn't write an assignment operator (`operator=`) for your `Animal` class, thus assignment will not work properly.  And why not use `std::vector` instead of doing this yourself?  Also, `std::string` instead of the C-string stuff.

Comment: Do not lol, but at my University they don't let you use these for your homework....yeah, it sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `animals` variable is an array of `Animal` and you need a pointer or reference to have polymorphic behavior.

You cannot build an array of references so you need an array of pointers: `Animal **animals`.

When you copy a `Monkey` for example into an `Animal` what you actually do is copy the animal part of the object and lose the monkey part. That is called *splicing* and is to be avoided almost alway.

PS: You should use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of managing your own memory.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit new at C++, but I'll see what can I do with this array of pointers stuff.

For the string and vector stuff: "Do not lol, but at my University they don't let you use these for your homework....yeah, it sucks." :)

Comment: @Arkluk: Yeah, I've suffered that univeritary stupidity. C++ is the only language where they will not let you use the standard library, simply because it didn't exist 25 years ago... Just don't get used to it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I marked it as the solution. I also copied the relevant code into the quesiton.